# How to keep a pylons web-application server running on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, python, service, pylons

We have a pylons web application running on a windows server 2003 machine.

There is a startup script that runs in a "dos box".

From time to time the script crashes and the server is then down. How to keep it runing / monitored?

*Edit*: On a linux box I would use a monitoring tool like "monit" that can check if the service responds to http requests and kills it and starts a new instance if not.

*Edit2*: After some research I found something now:

http://www.google.de/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.pylonshq.com%2Fdisplay%2Fpylonscookbook%2FHow%2Bto%2Brun%2BPylons%2Bas%2Ba%2BWindows%2Bservice

(the original site is down at the present, but google cache has the page: http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/How+to+run+Pylons+as+a+Windows+service )

I found the link on http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/deployment.html (2nd paragraph from the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered running it through IIS which can then monitor processes and restarts through application pools?  Check out:

http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/

and:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyisapie

I use the first, but the second has better performance.

Comment: would they also detect a crash and somehow restart?

Comment: Well, I have never had applications crash, that I am aware of.  I have had exceptions, but I trap my exceptions at a high level so they don't make it through to IIS.  However, I did have application pools designed to shut-down the application to conserve resources if the application hadn't been used in 20 minutes (this is the default behavior).  IIS knows that if a request comes in and there is no application in the application pool, that it needs to start the application.  I assume this would work the same if the application crashed.